# passing a pointer to a statically allocated matrix into a function - c

Tags: c, arrays, function, initialization

At the moment I have the below code which works:

```
/*int f_ls(char **buffer, unsigned int max_files);*/

char buffer_tmp[LS_MAX_FILES][MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH];
char *buffer[LS_MAX_FILES];
int i = 0;
while(i < LS_MAX_FILES)
{
    buffer[i] = buffer_tmp[i];
    i++;
}
int r = f_ls(buffer, LS_MAX_FILES);
```

However it had me thinking, why is it that a 2 dimensional array does not implicitly decay to pointers when passed into a function like a one with only a single dimension would?

2nd slightly less interesting question: Is there a cleaner way of doing the above that I'm missing? It seems like a lot of code just to initialise something to pass into a function.

In c++, I belive, you could do something slightly cleaner with new, but this still seems a little clunky.

Comment: Come on, now. In C++ you would use a vector of strings. If it's a return value (you're passing in un-initialized data, which indicates so) it would be *a return value* and this would just go away.

Comment: Yep, your right, in c++ there are nicer options. However, in c you could only achive a similar effect using dynamic memory allocation, which, in some situations is not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

A "two-dimensional" array *does* decay to a pointer, but it decays to a pointer to an array:

```
char (*ptr_to_buffer_tmp)[MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH]
```

Answer (score 1):

> why is it that a 2 dimensional array does not implicitly decay to pointers when passed into a function like a one with only a single dimension would?

A 2D array can be seen as array of 1D arrays.  Passing its name to a function will convert it to the pointer to the first 1D array (element) of 2D array.

> 2nd slightly less interesting question: Is there a cleaner way of doing the above that I'm missing? It seems like a lot of code just to initialise something to pass into a function.

Yes. What you have done is similar to passing the name of the 2D array.

```
int r = f_ls(buffer_tmp, LS_MAX_FILES);
```

Comment: Thanks, though I'm pretty sure I would at least get a compiler warning passing the array into a function that accepts a pointer-pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Your two-dimensional array:

```
char buffer_tmp[LS_MAX_FILES][MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH];
```

Cannot decay to a pointer to an array of pointers, because what would that mean for the in-memory representation?  Your buffer_tmp looks like this:

```
H E L L O   W O R L D
S O M E T H I N G
O K
```

Whereas your buffer looks like this:

```
0x1234 -> "HELLO WORLD"
0x5678 -> "SOMETHING"
0x9abc -> "OK"
```

I hope that helps: where in one you have a rectangle of characters, in the other you have a vector of pointers to strings which are elsewhere.  The function signature you're trying to use simply won't support the former, and it can't be written to support both at the same time (not in C anyway, try Fortran!).